# can i use the live playground platform, instead of local installation?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I wen through the environment setup detail and  got a problem.
The thing is my laptop is running out of resources. so i decided to utilize the online playground
environment for the tutorial. I just didn't want to make a local installation.
Tell me your words about it.
Thanks all in advance

Comment: At the time of writing playground platform isn't up to date. Progress about this issue is tracked here https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/issues/195

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As the online Plutus Playground is not available at the moment (see
[here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/issues/195)), and your local computer doesn't have the required resources (around 35GB of disk and 8GB of RAM), I'd recommend to run it in a Linux virtual machine in the cloud (AWS, Azure, Google Cloud, etc.), where you'll be able to pay only for the minutes of running time plus a small amount for the storage if you want it to persist, or you can look for a traditional VPS hosting that you can find for less than $10 a month. Cheers!